# How to correctly use JavaScript with Jade working with parameters passed in on render

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

So my question is about the correct place to link to external JavaScript files in a child Jade template, and passing data (if this is even possible?) to these JavaScript files.

So I am using Express, and rendering my Jade files with passed in data like so:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    tflSentimentAnalysis.fetchTflSentiments(credentials, function(results){
        res.render('twitterInsights', results);
    });
});
```

The data is now accessible the normal way in my twitterInsights.jade using the

`#{results.attributeName}`

I have a very simple Jade file, which extends from a Jade template, like so:

```
extend layout
block content
    h2 Title of page
    p Page contents will go here
```

And I need to include 2 JavaScript files. Firstly the D3.js library in bower_components and secondly my own JavaScript file in public/javascripts.

```
script(src="/bower_components/d3/d3.min.js")
script(src="/public/javascripts/twitterVisualisation.js")
```

**Where is the best position in the jade template to link to the JavaScript files?**

My JavaScript file (twitterVisualisation.js) requires the data passed into jade on render.

**How is the best way to pass this data to the JavaScript file?**

I have been searching for an answer to this for a while, and am surprised it's not a common question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility:

```
extend layout

block content
  script.
    var results = !{JSON.stringify(results)};

  h2 Title of page
  p Page contents will go here

  script(src="/bower_components/d3/d3.min.js")
  script(src="/public/javascripts/twitterVisualisation.js")
```

Basically, the `results` Jade variable is rendered to a JSON string and placed in a `results` client-side-JS variable that you can use from your other script(s). I usually don't prefer doing this myself (unless I have to) because it creates a global variable (`results`).

It depends on the internals of `twitterVisualisation.js` if there's perhaps a better way. For instance, if that file has a function that you call, you could rewrite it to something like this:

```
extend layout

block content
  script(src="/bower_components/d3/d3.min.js")
  script(src="/public/javascripts/twitterVisualisation.js")
  script.
    twitterVisualisationFunction( !{JSON.stringify(results)} );

  h2 Title of page
  p Page contents will go here
```

The order in which you render the results and load the other JS files depends on which method suits the rest of your code best.